# Extracting values using regex

Tags: c#, regex, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I want to extract the value "64,111" from this piece of text (html markup).

```
     <tr>
     <th id="abc-xyz">Page <span class="sub">avg</span></th>
    <td headers="abc-xyz">
    10th Aug, 2011  </td>
  <td headers="abc-xyz">64,111</td>
     </tr>
```

I am currently using this regex -:

```
Match m2 = Regex.Match(text, @"\<td headers=""abc-xyz""\>(.*?)\</td\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But no results ,Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

escape the double quote with `\`

```
Match m2 = Regex.Match(text, "(?<=<td\sheaders=\"abc-xyz\">).*(?=</td>)", 
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: When I am using @ symbol I guess there is no need for escaping a quote symbol.But it still doesn't help ,please suggest

Comment: `(?<=<td\sheaders="abc-xyz">).*(?=</td>)`

Comment: No it doesn't .and you are including (?=</td>)  in the () so that isn't required .It(mistake) should be something simple I guess ,I must be making some silly mistake in my code ,but I am not able to figure out what,the code I have written above, I am constantly editing and it works for all other tags.

Comment: Yes I can see you are absolutely right ,I am using Visual studio and using an @ symbol in front of the regex string, but it isn't working can you please write the regex using an @ symbol if you don't mind.like that written in my code.Sorry for acting like a fool.

Comment: `Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=<td\sheaders=""abc-xyz"">).*(?=</td>)", 
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "." use a character class excluding the stop character. That is, instead of `">(.*)<"` you want `">([^<]*)<"`.

I assume you know that this is no substitute for real parsing, which regex can't do, so I won't preach about that. There's already a really funny response somewhere on this site to that effect.

Comment: I guess you are in the right direction sir but still not working ,I even tried ">([^<]*?)\<" and ">([^<]*?)<" .

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with C#, but did you try removing the @ and escaping quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is more than one way to skin a cat.
Parsing XML is not limited to regex so here is one way to do it using Linq to XML.

```
string found = (from td in XElement.Parse(myxml).Elements("td")
                where td.HasAttributes
                let headers = td.Attribute("headers")
                where headers != null && headers.Value == "abc-xyz" && !td.HasElements
                select td.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

[Linq to XML tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1524/reading-xml-documents-using-linq-to-xml/)